# NoMethodError: Undefined method `first_or_create' for "foo":String

Tags: ruby, sinatra, datamapper

I have used this method before in a Sinatra application with Datamapper without any troubles.
Now it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas appreciated.
My test:

```
scenario 'add hashtags to posts' do
visit '/'
add_post('Stacca', 
        'Hello! out there',
         %w(foo bar))
post = Post.first
 expect(post.hashtag.map(&:text)).to include('foo')
 expect(post.hashtag.map(&:text)).to include('bar')
```

end

My server

```
post '/posting' do
username = params['username']
message = params['message']
hashtag = params['hashtag'].split(' ').map do |hashtag|
hashtag.first_or_create(text: hashtag)
end
Post.create(username: username, message: message, hashtag: hashtag)
redirect to ('/')
end
```

My Models:

```
class Post
include DataMapper::Resource
property :id, Serial
property :username, String
property :message, String

has n, :hashtag, through: Resource
end
```

and:

```
class Hashtag
include DataMapper::Resource
has n, :posts, through: Resource
property :id, Serial
property :text, String
end
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Hashtag.first_or_create(text: hashtag)
```

Hashtag should have been a class
i.e. you missed the capital

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
hashtag.first_or_create(text: hashtag)
```

should be:

```
Hashtag.first_or_create(text: hashtag) # uppercase!
```

Else, you are just trying to call a non existing "first_or_create" method on the String ("foo") you got from the scenario. 'Hashtag' is your class, 'hashtag' is your (String) variable.